# Woocomerce doesn't allow me to add variations to basket when I have more than 25 total variations

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi not sure if this is the best place to ask but was my first thought as I can't find anything on it elsewhere.

Basically My site has a products using woocomerce. These have been set up as variable products. Everything seemed to be working fine however when the attribute has over 25 variations in it I can no longer add the product to my basket?

To clarify the products I'm creating are online courses. The attribute for this product is the course date. Within this I have created around 35 different dates as variations which the user can select from a drop down.

This was working fine and when you select a date it can be added to the basket. However as soon as the number of variations ('Dates')i add to the product exceeds 25 the add to basket button always stays greyed out. I can no longer add any of the variants at all...

Truly is bizzare anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In my test site I created a product with 26 variations, which each one of them can be added to the cart (No error there). So I think it can be something else. Have you deactivate some plugins to avoid a conflict error? have you tried to change to a different, more light loaded Theme? (Storefront) The "console" of your browser shows some errors before and after you added de 25+ variations?

Comment: It's not specifically 25 it's just when I d large amounts. Try 40 perhaps? Does that still work for you? If so then yes perhaps some odd confliction with plugins which I will now consider.

Comment: Actually never mind, this does seem to be working for me now. I made no changes. How strange.